# How can i hide shown div if user did not hover mouse on shown div

Tags: jquery

I have two `divs` close to each other. When I hover over div one, div two is showing.

If I don't mouse hover on `div` two it should fadeout. Or if I move mouse from `div` one to elsewhere then also `div` two should fadeout.

```
$(".one").mouseover(function () {
    $(".two").show();
});
$(".two").mouseleave(function () {
  $(".two").fadeOut(1);
});
```

[Js Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/owaiskiani65/0y5mezu4/)

Answer (score 2):

You can add a `mouseover` event on body and act according to the current target. This will close/hide the element, if the mouse hovers anywhere in the body excpet `.one` and `.two`

```
$("body").mouseover(function (e) {
    if(!($(e.target).is('.one') || $(e.target).is('.two'))){
        $(".two").fadeOut();
    }
});
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0y5mezu4/6/)**

Answer (score 1):

Updated your [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/myTerminal/0y5mezu4/4/).

You could use another parent `div` and bind events to it, instead of `.one` and `.two`.

Comment: Updated your [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/myTerminal/0y5mezu4/12/). Some hackish scripts there, but yes, they work.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out.

```
$(".one").hover(function () {
$(".two").show();
},function(){
   if($(".two:hover").length==0) {
    $(".two").fadeOut();
}else{
    $(".two").mouseleave(function () {
        $(".two").fadeOut();
    });
}
});
```

Answer (score -1):

I did it by my self.

```
$(".one").mouseover(function () {
    $(".two").show();
});
$(".one").mouseleave(function () {
    if($(".two").is(":hover")){
    }else{
        $(".two").fadeOut();
    }
});
$(".two").mouseleave(function () {
    if($(".one").is(":hover")){
    }else{
        $(".two").fadeOut();
    }
});
```

[Updated Js Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/owaiskiani65/0y5mezu4/)